# How do I exclude children from having last-of-type selector applied?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I set up a simple css based dropdown navigation.

The last category of the main navigation (named login) is supposed to look different from the rest, hence I simply applied a different style via last-of-type.

However the style now gets applied to the drop-down menus as well, meaning the last item of the dropdowns have said style applied also.

(Also, I cannot target them with nth-... selector since there will be new categories added / removed every once in a while.)

How would I stop this form happening?

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1
    <ul>
      <li>subitem 1</li>
      <li>subitem 2</li>
      <li>subitem 3</li>  <-- unfortunately different style also...
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>login</li>  <-- different stlye
</ul>
```

Comment: show us your css, but i suppose you need [siblings selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a wrap for your unordered lis you can use something like this

```
<div class="test">
<ul>
  <li>item 1
    <ul>
      <li>subitem 1</li>
      <li>subitem 2</li>
      <li>subitem 3</li>  <!-- unfortunately different style also...-->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>login</li>  <!-- different stlye -->
</ul>
</div>
```

So the CSS

```
.test > ul > li:last-of-type{color:red;}
```

set style only for the first ul after div.test and doesn't affect the other nested elements

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxyzjx)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much.